# Safe modelling of relational data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, relational-database, type-safety, in-memory-database

I find it very common to want to model relational data in my functional programs. For example, when developing a web-site I may want to have the following data structure to store info about my users:

```
data User = User 
  { name :: String
  , birthDate :: Date
  }
```

Next, I want to store data about the messages users post on my site:

```
data Message = Message
  { user :: User
  , timestamp :: Date
  , content :: String
  }
```

There are multiple problems associated with this data structure:

- We don't have any way of distinguishing users with similar names and birth dates.
- The user data will be duplicated on serialisation/deserialisation
- Comparing the users requires comparing their data which may be a costly operation.
- Updates to the fields of `User` are fragile -- you can forget to update all the occurences of `User` in your data structure.

These problems are manageble while our data can be represented as a tree. For example, you can refactor like this:

```
data User = User
  { name :: String
  , birthDate :: Date
  , messages :: [(String, Date)] -- you get the idea
  }
```

However, it is possible to have your data shaped as a DAG (imagine any many-to-many relation), or even as a general graph (OK, maybe not). In this case, I tend to simulate the relational database by storing my data in `Map`s:

```
newtype Id a = Id Integer
type Table a = Map (Id a) a
```

This kind of works, but is unsafe and ugly for multiple reasons:

- You are just an `Id` constructor call away from nonsensical lookups.
- On lookup you get `Maybe a`, but often the database structurally ensures that there is a value.
- It is clumsy.
- It is hard to ensure referential integrity of your data.
- Managing indices (which are very much necessary for performance) and ensuring their integrity is even harder and clumsier.

**Is there existing work on overcoming these problems?**

It looks like Template Haskell could solve them (as it usually does), but I would like not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`ixset`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ixset) library (or [`ixset-typed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ixset-typed-0.5/docs/Data-IxSet-Typed.html), a more type-safe version) will help you with this. It's the library that backs the relational part of [`acid-state`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state), which also handles versioned serialization of your data and/or concurrency guarantees, in case you need it.

The Happstack Book has an [IxSet tutorial](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/index.html#ixset-a-set-with-multiple-indexed-keys).

---

The thing about `ixset` is that it manages "keys" for your data entries automatically.

For your example, one would create one-to-many relationships for your data types like this:

```
data User =
  User
  { name :: String
  , birthDate :: Date
  } deriving (Ord, Typeable)

data Message =
  Message
  { user :: User
  , timestamp :: Date
  , content :: String
  } deriving (Ord, Typeable)

instance Indexable Message where
  empty = ixSet [ ixGen (Proxy :: Proxy User) ]
```

You can then find the message of a particular user. If you have built up an `IxSet` like this:

```
user1 = User "John Doe" undefined
user2 = User "John Smith" undefined

messageSet =
  foldr insert empty
  [ Message user1 undefined "bla"
  , Message user2 undefined "blu"
  ]
```

... you can then find messages by `user1` with:

```
user1Messages = toList $ messageSet @= user1
```

If you need to find the user of a message, just use the `user` function like normal. This models a one-to-many relationship.

Now, for many-to-many relations, with a situation like this:

```
data User =
  User
  { name :: String
  , birthDate :: Date
  , messages :: [Message]
  } deriving (Ord, Typeable)

data Message =
  Message
  { users :: [User]
  , timestamp :: Date
  , content :: String
  } deriving (Ord, Typeable)
```

... you create an index with `ixFun`, which can be used with lists of indexes. Like so:

```
instance Indexable Message where
  empty = ixSet [ ixFun users ]

instance Indexable User where
  empty = ixSet [ ixFun messages ]
```

To find all the messages by an user, you still use the same function:

```
user1Messages = toList $ messageSet @= user1
```

Additionally, provided that you have an index of users:

```
userSet =
  foldr insert empty
  [ User "John Doe" undefined [ messageFoo, messageBar ]
  , User "John Smith" undefined [ messageBar ]
  ]
```

... you can find all the users for a message:

```
messageFooUsers = toList $ userSet @= messageFoo
```

If you don't want to have to update the users of a message or the messages of a user when adding a new user/message, you should instead create an intermediary data type that models the relation between users and messages, just like in SQL (and remove the `users` and `messages` fields):

```
data UserMessage = UserMessage { umUser :: User, umMessage :: Message } 

instance Indexable UserMessage where
  empty = ixSet [ ixGen (Proxy :: Proxy User), ixGen (Proxy :: Proxy Message) ]
```

Creating a set of these relations would then let you query for users by messages and messages for users without having to update anything.

The library has a very simple interface considering what it does!

**EDIT:** Regarding your "costly data that needs to be compared": `ixset` only compares the fields that you specify in your index (so to find all the messages by a user in the first example, it compares "the whole user").

You regulate which parts of the indexed field it compares by altering the `Ord` instance. So, if comparing users is costly for you, you can add an `userId` field and modify the `instance Ord User` to only compare this field, for example.

This can also be used to solve the chicken-and-egg problem: what if you have an id, but neither a `User`, nor a `Message`?

You could then simply create an explicit index for the id, find the user by that id (with `userSet @= (12423 :: Id)`) and then do the search.

Comment: Doesn't the one-to-many model shown here share all the disadvantages of the original model from the question?

Comment: @ehird, I make about 10 edits per minute, so I think that I've answered your concern along the way.

Comment: Yes, indeed. (BTW, acid-state doesn't actually depend on ixset; they're just designed to be used together.)

Comment: I got exception "stack overflow" when I try to evaluate `user1Messages = toList $ messageSet @= user1` in the second example. I think it's because I can't compare a datatype that has infinite recursion (User [Message [User ...). The first and third example works for me. Thx!

Answer (score 8):

IxSet is the ticket.  To help others who might stumble on this post here's a more fully expressed example,

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveDataTypeable, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main (main) where

import Data.Int
import Data.Data
import Data.IxSet
import Data.Typeable

-- use newtype for everything on which you want to query; 
-- IxSet only distinguishes indexes by type
data User = User 
  { userId :: UserId
  , userName :: UserName }
  deriving (Eq, Typeable, Show, Data)
newtype UserId = UserId Int64
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Show, Data)
newtype UserName = UserName String
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Show, Data)

-- define the indexes, each of a distinct type
instance Indexable User where
   empty = ixSet 
      [ ixFun $ \ u -> [userId u]
      , ixFun $ \ u -> [userName u]
      ]

-- this effectively defines userId as the PK
instance Ord User where
   compare p q = compare (userId p) (userId q)

-- make a user set
userSet :: IxSet User
userSet = foldr insert empty $ fmap (\ (i,n) -> User (UserId i) (UserName n)) $ 
    zip [1..] ["Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Alice"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Here, it's obvious why IxSet needs distinct types.
  showMe "user 1" $ userSet @= (UserId 1)
  showMe "user Carol" $ userSet @= (UserName "Carol")
  showMe "users with ids > 2" $ userSet @> (UserId 2)
  where
  showMe :: (Show a, Ord a) => String -> IxSet a -> IO ()
  showMe msg items = do
    putStr $ "-- " ++ msg
    let xs =  toList items
    putStrLn $ " [" ++ (show $ length xs) ++ "]"
    sequence_ $ fmap (putStrLn . show) xs
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been asked to write an answer using Opaleye.  In fact there's not an awful lot to say, as the Opaleye code is fairly standard once you have a database schema.  Anyway, here it is, assuming there is a `user_table` with columns `user_id`, `name` and `birthdate`, and a `message_table` with columns `user_id`, `time_stamp` and `content`.

This sort of design is explained in more detail in [the Opaleye Basic Tutorial](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/blob/master/Doc/Tutorial/TutorialBasic.lhs).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Opaleye
import Data.Profunctor.Product (p2, p3)
import Data.Profunctor.Product.TH (makeAdaptorAndInstance)
import Control.Arrow (returnA)

data UserId a = UserId { unUserId :: a }
$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pUserId" ''UserId)

data User' a b c = User { userId    :: a
                        , name      :: b
                        , birthDate :: c }
$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pUser" ''User')

type User = User' (UserId (Column PGInt4))
                  (Column PGText)
                  (Column PGDate)

data Message' a b c = Message { user      :: a
                              , timestamp :: b
                              , content   :: c }
$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pMessage" ''Message')

type Message = Message' (UserId (Column PGInt4))
                        (Column PGDate)
                        (Column PGText)


userTable :: Table User User
userTable = Table "user_table" (pUser User
  { userId    = pUserId (UserId (required "user_id"))
  , name      = required "name"
  , birthDate = required "birthdate" })

messageTable :: Table Message Message
messageTable = Table "message_table" (pMessage Message
  { user      = pUserId (UserId (required "user_id"))
  , timestamp = required "timestamp"
  , content   = required "content" })
```

An example query which joins the user table to the message table on the `user_id` field:

```
usersJoinMessages :: Query (User, Message)
usersJoinMessages = proc () -> do
  aUser    <- queryTable userTable    -< ()
  aMessage <- queryTable messageTable -< ()

  restrict -< unUserId (userId aUser) .== unUserId (user aMessage)

  returnA -< (aUser, aMessage)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another radically different approach to representing relational data is used by the database package [haskelldb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb).  It doesn't work quite like the types you describe in your example, but it is designed to allow a type-safe interface to SQL queries.  It has tools for generating data types from a database schema and vice versa.  Data types such as the ones you describe work well if you always want to work with whole rows.  But they don't work in situations where you want to optimize your queries by only selecting certain columns.  This is where the HaskellDB approach can be useful.

Comment: Nowadays I would suggest Opaleye instead of HaskellDB (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye) but I'm biased because I wrote it :)

Comment: @TomEllis: Would you consider writing a brief answer to this question using Opaleye?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete solution, but I suggest taking a look at the [ixset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ixset) package; it provides a set type with an arbitrary number of indices that lookups can be performed with. (It's intended to be used with [acid-state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state) for persistence.)

You do still need to manually maintain a "primary key" for each table, but you could make it significantly easier in a few ways:

1. Adding a type parameter to `Id`, so that, for instance, a `User` contains an `Id User` rather than just an `Id`. This ensures you don't mix up `Id`s for separate types.
2. Making the `Id` type abstract, and offering a safe interface to generating new ones in some context (like a `State` monad that keeps track of the relevant `IxSet` and the current highest `Id`).
3. Writing wrapper functions that let you, for example, supply a `User` where an `Id User` is expected in queries, and that enforce invariants (for example, if every `Message` holds a key to a valid `User`, it could allow you to look up the corresponding `User` without handling a `Maybe` value; the "unsafety" is contained within this helper function).

As an additional note, you don't actually need a tree structure for regular data types to work, since they can represent arbitrary graphs; however, this makes simple operations like updating a user's name impossible.